# Удаление символов в строке

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Есть строка, например, `String out = "qwerty";` Я хочу удалить из нее с 1 по 3 символы. Возможно ли это? Читал про метод delete, но он только для классов StringBuffer и StringBuilder. Если ли для String что-то похожее? Если нет, то как правильно скопировать строку из String в StringBuilder или StringBuffer и обратно?

Comment: [String.substring][1]


  [1]: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Comment: "Стандартными" средствами языка этого сделать нельзя. Строки (экземпляры класса String) в Java **не изменяемы** (immutable).

Можно либо сделать *новую* строку (конечно, никто не мешает присвоить ссылку не нее той же переменой), либо использовать [какой-нибудь хакинг](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146255/create-a-mutable-java-lang-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать метод substring(int indexBegin, int indexEnd), он вернёт вам строку начиная с позиции indexBegin до позиции indexEnd. Отсчёт символов ведется с нуля. Так же возможно применение того же метода, с одним параметром - indexBegin, который вернёт вам строку от указанного индекса до конца строки.

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, спасибо, про substring читал, но только про 2 параметра. С одним параметром даже более удобнее для меня. Только можно уточнить, он вернет строку вместе с первым указанным символом или после указанного символа?

Comment: Начиная с указанного. Например, в вашем случае, надо вызывать substring(4), тогда вернётся строка "rty"

Answer (score 2):

Используя **String**(да, у него нету как такого delete):

Если немного текста и не лень написать что-то своё, тогда как вариант сделать как-то так:

```
String deleteCharacters(String str, int from, int to) {
    return str.substring(0,from)+str.substring(to);
}
```

возвращает строку с удаленными символами в диапазоне [trom, to) (не включно с to)

```
String out = "qwerty";
out = deleteCharacters(out, 1, 3); //qrty
```

но мне больше нравиться когда в аргументы идёт количество после первой координаты. тогда:

```
String deleteSomeCharacters(String str, int from, int count) {
    return str.substring(0,from)+str.substring(from+count);
}
```

А если есть желание то можно поиграться и написать что-то с вырезанием больше чем одного диапазона символов используя вараргс(varargs), например:

```
String deleteSomeCharacters(String str, int...fromCount) {
    String newStr = new String(str);
    int deleter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fromCount.length; i+=2) {
        newStr = newStr.substring(0, fromCount[i]-deleter) +
            newStr.substring(fromCount[i]+fromCount[i+1]-deleter);
        deleter += fromCount[i+1];
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Используя **StringBuffer**:

```
String out = "qwerty";
//вызываем конструктор со строкой в качестве аргумента
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(out);
stringBuffer.delete(1,3);
out = stringBuffer.toString(); //qrty
```